# How to set vertically center Multiple views in some other view using Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to set two view vertically center in one another view like below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain the image view from top to the parent and from bottom to parent, your text constraint to the image from top and bottom and from start to the image too:

Here is some code for what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```